# Spring Data JPA - Specifications and Querydsl

Tags: spring, maven, jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to integrate QueryDSL to my existing project with Spring Data, I've tried different samples and now I've decided to stick to this one [Advanced Spring Data JPA - Specifications and Querydsl](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/).

**Problem**: when I run the project as Maven generate-sources I get this error

```
error: Annotation processor 'com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor' not found
```

I'm adding this plugin to my pom.xml as the blog post indicates:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

and the dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
     <artifactId>querydsl-sql</artifactId>
     <version>3.6.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to solve this or how to properly integrate QueryDSL to my project ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have `querydsl-apt` as a dependency?

Comment: sure, I'll update the post with the dependency detail

Comment: you need `querydsl-jpa` not `querydsl-sql`

Comment: I had querydsl-sql instead of querydsl-jpa, not sure whats the difference here...  I end up following this https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/tree/master/querydsl-jpa but using version 1.0 of the plugin since I couldn't get to make the last versin work

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The way I could make this work was using the **com.querydsl**.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor instead of the **com.mysema.query**.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor and by changing the dependencies as follow:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

The plugin end up like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
         <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I also executed in the command line at the projects root **mvn eclipse:eclipse** to update Eclipse to include the generated sources.

**Update:**

Replaced the plugin maven-apt-plugin for apt-maven-plugin and changed version to 1.1.3

Comment: Thank you for your example, works perfectly. Note: to avoid an exception like **"could not load entity class [...] NoClassDefFoundError: com/querydsl/core/types/dsl/EntityPathBase"**, it seems to be important to use the root **${project.build.directory}/generated-sources** and not a subdirectory in generated sources.

Comment: See related answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597466) with the example for lombok and mapstruct

Comment: For anyone who is reading, if you have multiple module maven structure, the entities that will be processed are only the ones in the module where you define plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of explicitly configuring the `apt-maven-plugin` just add the following dependency to the project (note the `jpa` classifier):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
  <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
  <classifier>jpa</classifier>
</dependency>
```

In case of Jakarta Persistence:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
  <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
  <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Also, if you want more Querydsl features than what `QuerydslPredicateExecutor` has to offer check out https://github.com/infobip/infobip-spring-data-querydsl#JPA.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following to fix it.

```
<querydsl.version>5.0.0</querydsl.version>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
<artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
<version>${querydsl.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
<artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
<version>${querydsl.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
<artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
<version>${querydsl.version}</version>
</dependency>
```